# Scala projects look awful with Eclipse Dark Theme

Tags: eclipse, scala, themes, scala-ide

I love Eclipse Dark Theme for Java projects. However, Scala projects are almost unreadable:

[image: ScalaIDE Dark Theme]

What can I do to fix this? Are there specialized Dark Themes for Scala projects?

Comment: Can't http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/ handle your Scala editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Scala has additional color settings, you need to use a theme designed for it, or be willing to tweak a lot of colors.

Choose from: http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?list=all&q=scala

Comment: Any idea where these scala themes are now? the site seems to be done for the whole week

Comment: @kisna I'm going to delete this answer.  I suggest reposting question or otherwise getting more attention, or... moving to Intellij.

Comment: No, I was not reposting, there are folks who *were able* to download this plugin before. And, one of the ways others can benefit, is, by exporting their preferences file .epf and share it with others.

This website is forever down, however, if somone could export their preference file for: http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=2075 and share it, it would make everyone's day!

If it might help others: the only thing I found decent:
https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme/blob/master/Eclipse/Tomorrow-Night.epf

File > Export (first to backup), then Import

Answer (score 7):

Okay, until someone does a better job at this, besides my above comments, I figured another theme and a way to get it, you can install any existing java theme, then modify the scala ide colors as you wish.
https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-moonrise-ui-theme

Export your preferences and add these at the end and then import:

```
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/org.scalaide.ui.config.defaultScalaHoverCss=/* It is also possible to change the font configuration here.\n * If one is configured, it will be preferred instead of the one\n * in the "Colors and Fonts" preference page.\n */\nhtml {}\n\nbody {\n  overflow\: auto;\n  margin\: 0.3em;\n}\n\nul {\n  list-style\: square;\n  margin-top\: 0;\n  margin-bottom\: 0;\n  margin-left\: 1em;\n}\n\nli {\n  margin-top\: 0.3em;\n  margin-bottom\: 0;\n}\n\ncode {\n  font-family\: monospace;\n  background-color\: \#eee;\n}\n\npre {\n  overflow\: auto;\n  background-color\: \#eee;\n}\n
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/org.scalaide.ui.config.defaultScalaHoverCss=/* It is also possible to change the font configuration here.\n * If one is configured, it will be preferred instead of the one\n * in the "Colors and Fonts" preference page.\n */\nhtml {}\n\nbody {\n  overflow\: auto;\n  margin\: 0.3em;\n}\n\nul {\n  list-style\: square;\n  margin-top\: 0;\n  margin-bottom\: 0;\n  margin-left\: 1em;\n}\n\nli {\n  margin-top\: 0.3em;\n  margin-bottom\: 0;\n}\n\ncode {\n  font-family\: monospace;\n  background-color\: \#eee;\n}\n\npre {\n  overflow\: auto;\n  background-color\: \#eee;\n}\n
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/org.scalaide.ui.config.defaultScalaHoverCss=/* It is also possible to change the font configuration here.\n * If one is configured, it will be preferred instead of the one\n * in the "Colors and Fonts" preference page.\n */\nhtml {}\n\nbody {\n  overflow\: auto;\n  margin\: 0.3em;\n}\n\nul {\n  list-style\: square;\n  margin-top\: 0;\n  margin-bottom\: 0;\n  margin-left\: 1em;\n}\n\nli {\n  margin-top\: 0.3em;\n  margin-bottom\: 0;\n}\n\ncode {\n  font-family\: monospace;\n  background-color\: \#eee;\n}\n\npre {\n  overflow\: auto;\n  background-color\: \#eee;\n}\n
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/org.scalaide.ui.config.scalaHoverCss=/* It is also possible to change the font configuration here.\n * If one is configured, it will be preferred instead of the one\n * in the "Colors and Fonts" preference page.\n */\nhtml {}\n\nbody {\n  overflow\: auto;\n  margin\: 0.3em;\n}\n\nul {\n  list-style\: square;\n  margin-top\: 0;\n  margin-bottom\: 0;\n  margin-left\: 1em;\n}\n\nli {\n  margin-top\: 0.3em;\n  margin-bottom\: 0;\n}\n\ncode {\n  font-family\: monospace;\n  background-color\: \#eee;\n}\n\npre {\n  overflow\: auto;\n  background-color\: \#eee;\n}\n
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/org.scalaide.ui.config.scalaHoverCss=/* It is also possible to change the font configuration here.\n * If one is configured, it will be preferred instead of the one\n * in the "Colors and Fonts" preference page.\n */\nhtml {}\n\nbody {\n  overflow\: auto;\n  margin\: 0.3em;\n}\n\nul {\n  list-style\: square;\n  margin-top\: 0;\n  margin-bottom\: 0;\n  margin-left\: 1em;\n}\n\nli {\n  margin-top\: 0.3em;\n  margin-bottom\: 0;\n}\n\ncode {\n  font-family\: monospace;\n  background-color\: \#eee;\n}\n\npre {\n  overflow\: auto;\n  background-color\: \#eee;\n}\n
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/org.scalaide.ui.config.scalaHoverCss=/* It is also possible to change the font configuration here.\n * If one is configured, it will be preferred instead of the one\n * in the "Colors and Fonts" preference page.\n */\nhtml {}\n\nbody {\n  overflow\: auto;\n  margin\: 0.3em;\n}\n\nul {\n  list-style\: square;\n  margin-top\: 0;\n  margin-bottom\: 0;\n  margin-left\: 1em;\n}\n\nli {\n  margin-top\: 0.3em;\n  margin-bottom\: 0;\n}\n\ncode {\n  font-family\: monospace;\n  background-color\: \#eee;\n}\n\npre {\n  overflow\: auto;\n  background-color\: \#eee;\n}\n
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.bracket.colour=249,250,244
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.default.colour=217,232,247
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.keyword.colour=221,40,103
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.multiLineComment.colour=98,98,98
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.multiLineString.colour=23,198,163
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.operator.colour=230,230,250
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.return.colour=221,40,103
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.scaladoc.colour=98,98,98
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.scaladoc.colour=98,98,98
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.annotation.colour=222,147,95
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.annotation.enabled=true
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.byNameParameterAtCallSite.colour=0,128,192
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.byNameParameterAtCallSite.enabled=true
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.caseClass.colour=240,198,116
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.caseClass.enabled=true
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.caseObject.colour=240,198,116
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.caseObject.enabled=true
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.class.colour=240,198,116
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.class.enabled=true
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.lazyTemplateVal.colour=0,128,255
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.localVar.colour=0,128,255
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.localVar.enabled=true
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.method.colour=128,255,0
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.method.enabled=true
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.methodParam.colour=0,128,192
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.methodParam.enabled=true
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.object.colour=240,198,116
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.object.enabled=true
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.package.colour=204,102,102
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.package.enabled=true
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.templateVal.colour=128,255,255
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.templateVal.enabled=true
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.templateVar.colour=128,255,255
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.templateVar.enabled=true
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.trait.colour=138,190,183
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.trait.enabled=true
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.type.colour=240,198,116
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.type.enabled=true
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.typeParameter.colour=240,198,116
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.semantic.typeParameter.enabled=true
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.singleLineComment.colour=98,98,98
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.string.colour=23,198,163
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.xml.attributeName=221,40,103
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.xml.attributeValue=23,198,163
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.xml.cdata=217,232,247
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.xml.comment=98,98,98
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.xml.equals=217,232,247
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.xml.processingInstruction=217,232,247
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.xml.tagDelimiter=217,232,247
/instance/org.scala-ide.sdt.core/syntaxColouring.xml.tagName=217,232,247
```

Then, edit the colors to your liking here:
[image]

It ends up looking like the Java equivalent.[image]

Of course, don't forget to share!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you an eclipse plugin: Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle.
It is a great plugin that works well with Scala code as well.

Link: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme-devstyle